# Is there a "personality test" for societies?

Tags: behavioral-economics, markets, scientific-method, history-economic-thought

You may have heard of the Myers Briggs personality profile test. Is there a similar test for societies?

The MB has four dimensions

- Introversion/Extraversion
- iNtuition/Sensing
- Feeling/Thinking
- Perception/Judging

I'm thinking that a society (which could be as large as a nation, or as small as an office) will have other attributes, such as

- Patriarchal/Matriarchal
- Corporate/Entrepreneur
- Rural/Urban
- Centralized/Decentralized (government)
- Religious/Secular

etc. Does a "society profile test" like that already exist?  Hopefully with data already collected?

Sorry if this is off topic. I couldn't find any "sociology stack exchange"

Comment: Strictly speaking this is off-topic here, although economists are constantly on the lookout for non-economic traits  to incorporate into their models. The good news is that even if the question gets closed, it already received an apparently stimulating answer.

Comment: Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnopsychology

Comment: There's also [Cognitive Sciences SE](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[Jonathan Haidt](http://www8.gsb.columbia.edu/rtfiles/leadership/Graham_Jesse_paper.pdf) has used a five axis model to characterize groups by their use of 5 sets of moral intuitions.

> Harm/care, Fairness/reciprocity, Ingroup/loyalty, Authority/ respect,
>   and Purity/sanctity. Across 4 studies using multiple methods, liberals
>   consistently showed greater endorsement and use of the Harm/care and
>   Fairness/reciprocity foundations compared to the other 3 foundations,
>   whereas conservatives endorsed and used the 5 foundations more
>   equally.

[He's got several papers in this area](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Jonathan%20Haidt%20authority%20%20purity&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C21). I don't know of any attempts to use this framework to describe groups other than liberals, conservatives, and libertarians, but in principle you could.